# How to pass javascript array's value inside a htmlstring for changed the innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, fetch

i have the following code

```
resultElement.innerHTML = '';

  fetch(`https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/`)
  .then(resp => resp.json()) // transform the data into json - an array with all the element
  .then(resp => 
    resp.map(({continent,native,languages})=>({continent,native,languages}))) 


  .then((resp) => {
    for(var i = 0;i <resp.length;i++){
      console.log(resp[i].continent,resp[i].native,resp[i].languages);

      resultElement.innerHTML = '<h5>Continent:</h5>' + 
      '<pre>' + (resp[i].continent, '\t') + '</pre>' + ' ' +

      '<h5>Native:</h5>' + 
      '<pre>' + (resp[i].native, '\t') + '</pre>'; 
    }
  }
)


}
```

in the above code, the htmlString just shows the h5 tag but not any value inside it. I want to shows all the arrays value inside the  tag. Unfortunately, it didn't work and I am not able to find any suitable solution for this. But it shows in the console.

Comment: Do not use comma as it would only return `\t`, instead concatenate `(resp[i].native + '\t')` https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/mzy1d0eb/. Also `resultElement.innerHTML += '<` instead of `resultElement.innerHTML = '<`

Comment: @bappi, If I'm right, you are overwriting the html in each iteration. Try concatenating and storing the result of the loop inside a separate variable and then user that variable with innerHTML

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is, but for strings like this try to use temlate literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I am curious, what is `resp.map(({continent,native,languages})=>({continent,native,languages}))` supposed to do, copy an array of objects?

Comment: @amn yes it is. It only copies this object from the url.

Comment: @shrys += did the trick. Thanks man. It help me a lot.

Comment: You don't need to copy anything -- you only need to work with one copy of parsed JSON anyway -- the object resolved by the promise returned by `resp.json()`. Copying, in your case, is absolutely unnecessary -- you discard the original object anyway. You can discard the entire `.then(resp => resp.map(({continent,native,languages})=>({continent,native,languages})))` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use comma as [`(resp[i].continent, '\t')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) as it would only return `\t`, instead concatenate: `(resp[i].native + '\t')`. Also, you need to concatenate the HTML markup with `+=`, instead of assigning it:

```js
resultElement.innerHTML = '';
fetch(`https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/`)
  .then(resp => resp.json()) // transform the data into json - an array with all the element
  .then(resp => resp.map(({ continent, native, languages }) => ({ continent, native, languages })))
  .then((resp) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
      //console.log(resp[i].continent, resp[i].native, resp[i].languages);
      resultElement.innerHTML += '<h5>Continent:</h5>' + '<pre>' + (resp[i].continent + '\t') + '</pre>' + ' ' + '<h5>Native:</h5>' + '<pre>' + (resp[i].native + '\t') + '</pre>';
    }
  })
```

```html
<div id="resultElement"></div>
```

---

A tabular implementation:

```js
resultElement.innerHTML = '';
fetch(`https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/`)
  .then(resp => resp.json()) // transform the data into json - an array with all the element
  .then(resp => resp.map(({ continent, native, languages }) => ({ continent, native, languages })))
  .then((resp) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
      //console.log(resp[i].continent, resp[i].native, resp[i].languages);
      resultElement.innerHTML +='<tr><td>' + (resp[i].continent + '\t') + '</td>' + '<td>' + (resp[i].native + '\t') + '</td>';
    }
  })
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Continent</td>
      <td>Native</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="resultElement"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but right now i wanted to show those attribute inside a table with header Continent Native & Language. It will be great if you help me for that.

Comment: let specific_tbody = document.getElementById(tbody_id); let row = specific_tbody.insertRow(index)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow